# Javascript rotates image accidentally

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, filereader, form-data

I have a Vue application which need to upload images on server like FormData. As I found out if image is too big Javascipt accidentally rotate the image by 90°. I dont understand it. There is not command to make any changes on image. This is the code:

```
uploadFiles(files) {
        this.validateUploadFiles(files);

        if( this.uploadErrors?.length ) return;

        this.loading = true;

        const timestamp = Date.now();
        files.forEach( (file, index) => {
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

            fileReader.onload = () => {
                const image = new Image();
                image.src = fileReader.result;

                image.onload = async () => {
                    const formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append("file", file);
                    formData.append("index", index);
                    formData.append("timestamp", timestamp);  // This is cause we need to delete prev old remaining files.

                    try {
                        const result = await this.$api.media.uploadCampaignPdfExportMedia( this.campaignId, formData );
                        this.uploadSuccess.push(result.data.fileName);
                    } catch ( error ) {
                        console.log(error);
                        this.uploadErrors.push( this.$t("campaign.upload.error.upload_failed", {name: file.name}) );
                    }
                };
            };
        });
        this.loading = false;
    },
```

I dont understand what happened there. Can somebody tell me please what is going on?

Comment: I know that many applications for image visualization automatically rotate the images if they are too big, in order to present the best aspect ratio. Are you sure that the images get actually rotated and it's not just the software to visualize it?

Comment: As I store it on the server the image is rotated.

Comment: Also if you manually upload it?

Comment: The problem is that some computers works fine without any problems but one computer does this. Its weird.

Comment: by "computer" you mean client, don't you?

Comment: by the way, we can also make hypothesis if you don't provide a reproducible example

Comment: Yes I meant clients. Its dificult to make reproducible example if some clients works fine and one of them does this issue. Also production script is under the login... It drives me crazy.